# Cannot Change Max Upload Size in File Field From 8mb

Tags: nodes, files

I have made changes to etc/php5/apache2/php.ini to increase max file upload size to 100mb but when I try to raise or lower the file upload size when creating a file field in a content type, it says that the current limit 8 MB even though the field saves the previous input. Anyone have any experience with this issue and could provide a solution?

Comment: Hi, glad you got your problem sorted but as this is a server-config question, nothing to do with Drupal, I have to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three variables in php.ini that could be limiting your upload size.

Look for the following in php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

I imagine one of these is set to 8M in your case.

Also, you will most likely have to restart apache after making the change to php.ini.

Comment: post_max_size was not included in the php.ini so I added it and set it and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

While working with Drupal site, to increase/decrease memory of PHP, you can use

```
ini_set('memory_limit','100M');
```

in the ***settings.php*** file.

You can verify the memory limit by going to **Status Report** of your site, i.e. ***admin/reports/status*** where you can see PHP Version, PHP Memory Limit, etc.